# Is it possible to styling log for XCode

Tags: xcode, logging, nslog

Now I was use `NSLog()` for debugging inside IDE, Is it possible to styling Log in Xcode ?

**Example**

- Coloring Log
- XML, JSON Output in Log console Styling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the XcodeColors xcode plugin to colorize log statements in the Xcode console:
https://github.com/robbiehanson/XcodeColors

It's very easy to use in combination with CocoaLumberjack:
https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaLumberjack/wiki/XcodeColors

For example, with Lumberjack, one line of code allows you to set the color for all error messages. You could make them show up in red so they're easily distinguishable from other debug logging.